# Record audio in metro application

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, voice-recording

I need a basic sample to know how I can record voice in metro application (C#)?

Answer (score 1):

Search for `MediaCapture API` to find information about that.

MSDN `MediaCapture` class reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR241124?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

There is a method called `StartRecordToStreamAsync`, which takes `MediaEncodingProfile` as a parameter. You can create a profile for MP3-only capture using `MediaEncodingProfileCreateMp3()` static method:

```
var profile = MediaEncodingProfileCreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High)
```